# New popup windows on Google Chrome for Windows are always the full screen width

Tags: windows, google-chrome, popup

I have a site http://bizfriend.ly/lesson.html?1 which requires several popups of specific widths. I cannot get the predefined widths to work for Windows versions of Chrome. It works fine in IE, Safari, and Chrome on Mac.

After step two in the instructions, your screen should have two popup windows next to each other.
[image]

The following function is called by a jQuery click function. Again it works fine all browsers except Chrome on Windows.

```
function _instructionsLinkClicked(evt){
    var url = 'instructions.html?'+lessonId;
    var width = 340;
    var height = window.screen.height;
    var left = window.screen.width - 340;
    instructionOptions = "height="+height+",width="+width+",left="+left;
    window.open(url,"instructions",instructionOptions);
  }
```

An interesting clue, when the 'Restore Down' button is clicked, the window reduces to the correct size I want, yet at the wrong location.